# ASP.net two dependent pagemethods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, latency, pagemethods

I have the following webmethods in the code behind page

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string BindDataTable()
{
  //This function connects to db gets the result and binds a datatable
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string DeleteItems(int[] ids)
{
 //This function deletes the items
}
```

In the aspx page i have an element that is triggering both page methods

```
 <a href="#"  onclick="Delete()"> Delete</a>
```

and the Delete js function is the following

```
     function Delete(){
PageMethods.DeleteItems(selectedIds);
PageMethods.BindDataTable();
   }
```

Inspecting the console in firebug is showing that both Pagemethods are triggered
successively

1. DeleteItems
2. BindDataTable

However, sometimes the BindDataTable is starting before the delete function is finished committing to database which keeps the table from being visually updated without a refresh.

Any idea how to trigger calling a pagemethod just after a previous pagemethod finishes it's server side commands ?
Thanks

Comment: I tried calling RegisterStartupScript method to call the Binding pagemethod from JS on the C# DeleteItems function end. The issue that most of the arguments of the RegisterStartupScript function can't be used there because the WebMethod is static .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi James ,

```
          I found one alternate way first call the delete web method once it completed on its success call BindDataTable web method . might be it work
```

function Delete(){

```
       PageMethods.DeleteItems(selectedIds);
        function onSucess(result) {
            PageMethods.BindDataTable();
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Something wrong.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Parth :D :) It was that easy !
Please accept this gift
http://rlv.zcache.com.au/gift_idea_for_computer_programmer_butterfly_hat-r09ef249668564a338d5184c64489798b_v9wfy_8byvr_324.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should call those two methods **synchronously**, see this post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/06/calling-web-service-methods-synchronously-in-asp-net-ajax.aspx

Or you could call the second method inside first method, if you don't need it for something else.

Comment: Thanks Robert, The first link is using c# posting for an ASMX file which is not my case. My webmethods are in the code behind of the same page and I am calling them using PageMethods.FunctionName() from clientside.
And conerning the second suggestion, please refer to the first comment on my question